# Twitter bootstrap - nesting rows vs multiple rows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I started to use Twitter bootstrap for this application that I am working on.

I read the documentation about nesting rows in both fixed grid system and in fluid one.

Now, I want to do something like this

[image]

So of course I could do something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span 12">red</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span 3">yellow</div>
            <div class="span 9">green</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I think I would get what I want. But I am wondering what are the consequences of doing

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span 12">red</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span 3">yellow</div>
        <div class="span 9">green</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't see any difference now in my browser but I am wondering what will happen if I include multiple row elements in single `container` tag. Is the row-nesting the only proper way to create something like I showed? What is the difference between those two implementations of my design, so to speak?

Comment: As you actually wants two rows I'd go for the second example. Also note you have a space in your classnames that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I agree with @jtheman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second version is more correct. But both work. The difference is how it responds when the page is re-sized. The second version will shrink and react better

However if you want the containers to match the above image you need to use `class="container-fluid"` and `class="row-fluid"`

Also remove the spaces between the spans and numbers

```
class="span 3"
```

Should say

```
class="span3"
```

Comment: About the spaces: good point, thanks! About the `fluid`, why is that? From what I understand the difference between `fluid` and `fixed` is the nesting rules (sum to 12 vs sum to parent), is there something more to this? I am still a beginner and I don't fully grasp all of the nuances of bootstrap.

Comment: adding `-fluid` to your container or row classes will essentially make the objects expand to their parent objects width. So if your parent object for `class="conrainer-fluid"` is the `<body>` object, then the `class="container-fluid"` object will expand to the `<body>` width.

Comment: Here are some good examples:

[class="container-fluid"](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html)
- Notice the big margins on the sides are missing

[class="container"](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html)
-Notice the big margins on the sides

Comment: No problem. I used Bootstrap-Twitter when I built [Maximum Talent](http://www.maxtalent.com). I loved it!